# Proving $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\xi ^n}{n}$ is not uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis

Proving $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\xi ^n}{n}$ is not uniformly  convergent for $\xi \in (0,1)$.

I am trying to do the above. I have attempted to show it is not a cauchy sequence by considering $||\frac{\xi ^n}{n} ||_{\sup}$ but no avail. Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series fails to converge uniformly if you can show there is some $\epsilon_0 > 0$ such that for every $N \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$\sup_{\xi \in (0,1)} \sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{\xi^n}{n}\geqslant \epsilon_0.$$

Notice that

$$\sup_{\xi \in (0,1)} \sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{\xi^n}{n}\geqslant \sup_{\xi \in (0,1)} \sum_{n=N+1}^{2N}\frac{\xi^n}{n}\geqslant \sup_{\xi \in (0,1)}N\frac{\xi^{N+1}}{2N} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Hence, using $\epsilon_0 = 1/2$ confirms the negation and the series is not uniformly convergent on $(0,1)$.

Comment: could you explain the last inequality

Comment: The sum from $N+1$ to $2N$ has N terms each smaller than $\xi^{n}/2N$,  and since $0 < \xi < 1$ this bound on each term is smaller than $\xi^{N+1}/2N$. So the supremum of the sum is greater than supremum of $\xi^{N+1}/2$ -- which is $1/2$.

Comment: This argument is fairly common for proving non-uniform convergence of series.  We are showing the tail fails to converge uniformly to 0. At the same time we show the sequence of partial sums is not Cauchy.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. Each term is smaller than $\xi^n / 2N$, I understand that. But how does that give us the required inequality. You've only used $0 < \xi < 1$ at the end?

Comment: I do understand the argument, just not how you bounded it - I was trying to bound it before I posted this question

Comment: No the supremum (least upper bound) of $\xi^{N+1}$ over (0,1) is $1$.  The interval need not be$(0,1]$ for the supremum to be $1$.

Comment: For any $\epsilon$ you can find $\xi \in (0,1)$ such that $1 > \xi^{N+1} > 1-\epsilon$

Comment: I understand that. I just don't see why supremum of  $N$ times $\xi ^{N+1} / 2N$ is less than or equal to the sum above. Why $N$ times?

Comment: The sum is $\sum_{k=N+1}^{2N}a_n = a_{N+1} + a_{N+2} + \ldots a_{2N}$. Each $a_n > b$.  Hence the sum is greater than $Nb$ since there are $N$ terms.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show for $z$ close to $1$ that the convergence of the series becomes arbitrarily slow. More formally, show the negation of uniform convergence: There exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all positive integers $N$, there exists $z \in (0,1)$ and $n \geq N$ such that $|f_n(z) - f(z)| \geq \epsilon$. Here $f_n$ is the $n$th partial sum of your series, and $f$ is the limiting function. It should be clear that this is true because you can choose $z$ to be whatever you want, arbitrarily close to $1$.

Comment: Isn't that the same as trying to bound the supremum from below? I've tried :(

Comment: @toothandcup2 I elaborated the answer.

Comment: I understand what you  mean, and I tried that before hand. I considered $||f_n - f_{n-1}||_{\sup} = ||\frac{\xi ^n}{n} ||_{\sup}$ and tried to show that was $\geq $something, but I couldn't find that "something"

Comment: You will get $1/n$ for the $\sup$ and then you can't bound it from below for arbitrary $n$. Instead, show what I described, by choosing $z$ and considering $|f(z) - f_n(z)|$ instead of $|f_n - f_{n-1}|_1$. Alternatively, look at $|f_{2n} - f_n|_1$, since if you can bound that from below then you have shown non-Cauchy.

Comment: but I do not know what $f(z)$ is

Comment: Try $|f_{2n} - f_n|_1$. Since the harmonic series approaches $\ln n$ up to a constant additive constant, you should get something like $\ln 2$ for a lower bound

Comment: I just tried, I'm not sure how you got $\log 2 $ as a lower bound. I'm still getting 0 as a lower bound

Comment: Nevermind - still stuck

Comment: $1/2n$ is not a constant lower bound, so it doesn't refute Cauchy. I'll add another answer showing how to get the $\ln 2$ lower bound

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_n$ be the $n$th partial sum function, and consider $|f_{2n} - f_n|_1$. This is equal to

$$H_{2n} - H_n$$

where $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n 1/k $ is the $n$th harmonic series partial sum. As $n \to \infty,$ we have $H_n \to \ln n + \lambda$ for some constant $\lambda$ independent of $n$ (look up Euler constant if you haven't seen this before). Then

$$H_{2n} - H_n \simeq \ln 2n - \ln n = \ln 2$$.