# question about uniform convergence of series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

(i) Show that the series $S= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$ is uniformly convergent on $(0,q)$ for each $0<q<1$.

(ii) Is $S$ uniformly convergent on $(0,1)$?

So $\frac{dS}{dx}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$  (for $\vert x \vert <1$)

So $S=\int \frac{1}{1-x} dx=-ln(1-x)=s(x)$

Need to show partial sums $s_n(x)$ converge uniformly to $s(x)$ on $(0,q)$

$s_n(x)=\int \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}dx$. But I couldn't do this integral (tried by parts to no avail...)

Also I'm not sure about (ii)...Isn't $(0,1)$ the same as $(0,q)$?

Any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For (ii), see the answers to this question:  [Proving $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\xi ^n}{n}$ is not uniformly convergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179843/proving-sum-n-1-infty-frac-xi-nn-is-not-uniformly-convergent/1179894#1179894)

For (i), show that $|S (x) - s_n(x)| < (1/n)q^n/(1-q)$. Note that this inequality breaks if $q = 1$, it is only valid for $|q| < 1$. So $q < 1$ is not the same case as $q = 1$.